# Swift: Multiple conditions in IF statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm currently trying to validate a sign up page using an if statement with multiple conditions.

At the same time, I want to validate the email address with a correct email format.

Below is each field should essentially be checked.

```
@IBAction func createAccountButton(_ sender: Any) {

    //check if textfields are empty and display alert
    let providedEmailAddress = emailTextField.text
    let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress!)


    if ( isEmailAddressValid || (firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! || (lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! || (usernameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! || (phoneNumberTextField.text?.isEmpty)! || (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        let alertViewController = SCLAlertView().showInfo("Failed to create account", subTitle: "One or more fields are empty, please check and try again.")
    } else {
        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Creating account...")
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 4)
    }
}
```

The variable `isEmailAddressValid` is linked to this function I found on [this site](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/validate-email-address-code-example-in-swift/).

```
// Check if email address entered is of the valid format
    func isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: String) -> Bool {

        var returnValue = true
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegEx)
            let nsString = emailAddressString as NSString
            let results = regex.matches(in: emailAddressString, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))

            if results.count == 0
            {
                returnValue = false
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            returnValue = false
        }

        return  returnValue
    }
```

However, when testing I realised when I enter a value in each field except the `emailTextfield.text` and click to create an account, the `else` part of the statement is executed.

Moreover when all fields have a value, I would assume the `else` part of the statement WILL execute, but the 'failed to create an account' alert is displayed instead.

What am I doing wrong and what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this part

```
if ( isEmailAddressValid |
```

with

```
if ( !isEmailAddressValid |
```

Comment: What does adding the ! at the front do? Adding it to the end force unwraps.

Comment: @daanyyaal `!someBoolValue`  means `someBoolValue == false`. You should read [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309)

Comment: No, `!someBoolValue` does not mean `someBoolValue == false`. `!someBoolValue` means that the value of `someBoolValue` is negated. If it was `true`, it is changed to `false`. If it was `false`, it is changed to `true`.

Comment: @rmaddy Let's assume `someBoolValue` has type `Bool` (like `isEmailAddressValid` in the original question). Can you provide and example where `!someBoolValue` and  `someBoolValue == false` do produce different behaviours?

Comment: I think I see the confusion. I read your earlier comment as stating that negating a bool makes the bool false (which of course isn't necessarily correct). Now I realize you are talking about `if` statements with those expressions. If that's the case then you are correct. `if !someBool {` works the same as `if someBool == false {`.

Comment: @rmaddy Exactly. There are differences if the type is `Bool?` instead of `Bool` though.